# Retrieve logged in User Photo from Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have hosted our web application in azure PaaS. We have used Active Directory authentication in our web application. We have used the below Graph URL and GraphApiVersion to get the user details from Azure AD.
GraphApiVersion="2013-11-08"
GraphUrl ="https://graph.windows.net"

We are able to fetch the logged in user details from azure AD but we are not able to get the logged in user photo from azure AD. Kindly share the c# sample code to fetch the logged in user photo from azure AD.

Thank you.

Comment: could you pls show me your code to `fetch the logged in user details from azure AD`? Per my understanding, they should use the same method.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

To retrieve the profile photo of logged-in user can be Ms Graph  in graph explorer please try the below query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value
```

**Response:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var stream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

**Response:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Use Microsoft Graph to Retrieve Users Photos and Store Them as Azure Blobs With C# – Mihai-Albert.com](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/08/12/use-microsoft-graph-to-retrieve-users-photos-and-store-them-as-azure-blobs-with-c/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please share the full source code for the reference.